# Python Logging in Docker

Tags: python, docker

I am test running python Script in Docker Container on Ubuntu Web Server. I am trying to find the Log file generated by Python Logger Module. Below is my Python Script

```
import time
import logging



def main():

    logging.basicConfig(filename="error.log", level=logging.DEBUG)

    start_time = time.time()
    logging.debug("Program starts running at %d", start_time)


    i = 0
    while i < 1000:
        print(i)
        i += 1

    while_time = time.time() - start_time

    logging.debug("Program ends running at %d", while_time)

    start_time = time.time()

    logging.debug("Program starts running at %d", start_time)

    for x in range(0, 100):
        print(x)

    if_time = time.time() - start_time

    print('While took - %s Seconds' % while_time )
    print('If took - %s Seconds' % if_time )

    logging.debug("Program ends running at %d", start_time)


main()
```

I have searched and found that Docker file produces Log file in json format in `/var/lib/docker/container/{con_id}/{con_id}.log`
This log file only includes the stdout and I cannot find the Log file generated by Python. Is there any way to retrieve the file.

Comment: Whats there in error.log file, You have written a script to write a logs in that file than why are you checking in docker logs locations.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have specified file `'error.log'` in command `logging.basicConfig(filename="error.log", level=logging.DEBUG)` for `logger` to put your logs into. This file is located inside your container and since containers are stateless, you have to mount the log file somewhere in your local machine in order to have access after powering off your container. You can read [this](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) for more information.

BTW, if you want to access the log file while it's already up, you can use `exec` option of the docker to make an interactive shell through the container and find the logs:

```
docker exec -it ${container_name}
```

[This](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/) documentation will helpful for `exec` commandline option.

Comment: On linux, `docker exec -it ${container_name} bash` followed by `ls` worked for me.