# Cron python job and Docker logs

Tags: python, docker, cron, stdout

I have a Python script that is running in a docker container as a cron job, I would like to see the stdout in docker logs for example I have in my script the following line

```
print("BT: " + bt)
```

I would like to see this output when I am running `docker logs some-container` 
my cron job as following

```
* * * * * root /usr/local/bin/python /opt/platform-location/platform-location.py >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1
```

and I am running the `cron` from Dockerfile as following:

```
FROM python:3

WORKDIR /opt/platform-location
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
COPY URLs.txt URLs.txt
COPY platform-location.py   platform-location.py
COPY platform-location.cron /etc/cron.d/platform-location
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/platform-location
RUN touch /var/log/cron.log
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get -y install cron vim
CMD cron && tail -f /var/log/cron.log
```

could you help me, please?

PS: it is not duplicate of Python Logging in Docker because I want to see the output when I am running docker logs command not docker exec command. 
also I am using cron which the other question reporter does not use.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Logging in Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48657323/python-logging-in-docker)

Comment: @HampusLarsson no it is not, I want to see the output when I am running docker logs command not docker exec command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is not with a python script, did you verify the cron logs without python for `CMD cron && tail -f /var/log/cron.log`?

Use the below image, I am sure the above snippet will working fine but the cron not able to write logs to console so as a result the python will not write too.

Here is the working example.

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine3.9
COPY test.py /test.py
RUN cat /test.py
RUN echo "* * * * * echo hello" | crontab - 

RUN echo "* * * * * python /test.py" | crontab -

CMD ["crond","-f"]
```

test.py

```
my_string = "Hello, World!"
print(my_string)
```

The image contain Python version `3.7.4`. You can change the base image to any [python version](https://hub.docker.com/_/python) will work fine if based on alpine.

**Updated:**
Double-check your python file existence on the specified location, As here is the working example that you can try.

```
FROM python:3.6
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install cron vim

WORKDIR /opt/platform-location
RUN echo "* * * * * root /usr/local/bin/python /opt/platform-location/platform-location.py >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1" >> /etc/cron.d/platform-location
RUN echo 'print ("hello World! ")' >> /opt/platform-location/platform-location.py
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/platform-location
RUN touch /var/log/cron.log
CMD cron && tail -f /var/log/cron.log
```

Comment: Thank you, I could not use your solution because I am not using crontab. I modified my question to include my Dockerfile. could you please check again and tell me what should I change?

Comment: BTW why? and I think there is no such big difference between crontab and cron?